# Calling a function is resulting in a required positional argument error

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, opencsv

I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious but here is the function and how I am calling it

```
def read_csv(fin):
    df = pd.read_csv(fin, sep='\t', low_memory=False)

    return df

df_p = read_csv('data.txt')
```

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: read_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fin'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that you called the function elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the read_csv line. You also have an extra comma at the end of the function call.

```
def read_csv(fin):
  df = pd.read_csv(fin, sep='\t',low_memory=False)
```